# Postgresql driver not found for maven dependency

Tags: spring, postgresql, maven, dependencies, driver

I am running a spring project with maven and I am trying to use postgresql. I've added the dependency to pom.xml, but at tomcat startup, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

It appears that Maven isn't downloading the jar so the Driver class is not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you got warnings during your build? Are you behind a proxy? Have you checked if the artifacts has been downloaded or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven wasn't recognizing the new dependency I have added to pom.xml, so I added it through 'Dependency view' from the xml and that did the trick. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 14):

What also worked for me if you are on intellj:
right klick pom.xml->Maven->Reimport
Don't know why it doesn't download the artifact on copy paste.

Comment: In my case it was: Right-click on pom.xml ->Maven->Reload project

Comment: Worked for me as well. Can you please explain why this is needed? I'm new to the Java world.

Comment: I know, I'm a bit late ^^ sorry for that. Maven is a package manager that organizes your java libraries. These are defined by your pom.xml The reload downloads the libraries und manages the required versions based on a parent version, if given. So if something during the download went wrong, you might not have the required libs. As a fix, you have to reload them

Answer (score 5):

When I put this in my pom, the artifact gets downloaded. Maybe you should clean your maven repository cache or delete the folders manually and retry.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. Still I receive the class not found exception. Do I need to add something else to pom.xml header? My current header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

Comment: So is the jar not existing or just not loaded?

Comment: Yes, the jar didn't exist. It wasn't downloaded

Answer (score 2):

If you came here for "missing artifact" error, This worked for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1212</version>
    </dependency>
```

For PostgreSQL 10 I use this:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild the artifact, most likely only the added dependency was not included there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was from the `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` configuration option for the maven-shade-plugin.

Previously, I set this configuration to `true` to make my shaded JAR file smaller due to the 10MB limit on AWS Lambda application.

After trying everything on SOF and nothing worked, I tried commenting out the `minimizeJar` option and it just worked flawlessly...

---

This is my working config for maven-shade-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <!-- <configuration>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
      </configuration> -->
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I ran the Maven project using the following steps:

1. `mvn clean package && mvn clean install`
2. `java -cp target/example-1.0.0.jar com.example.mainClassName`

Answer (score -1):

You need to place a copy of the jar in the tomcat/lib folder.

Comment: Tomcat manages the connections? No. Tomcat is a servlet engine but not an application server like Glassfish, JBoss, Weblogic etc.

Comment: This will not change a thing, cause the best in such cases is to put the driver into the resulting war file which will be deployed. That's it.