# Spring Data java configuration doesn't find the org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, classnotfoundexception

I have a project based on Spring Framework and it is initialized based only on Java configuration.

### TECHNOLOGIES USED:

- Java 8
- Spring framework 4.2.1.RELEASE
- Hibernate ORM 5.0.4.Final
- Spring Tool Suite IDE 3.6.2
- Maven 3
- Tomcat 7

**pom.xml**
....

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1205-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

....

### Database Configuration Files

I created the following configuration class.

whereas **SystemSettings** holds the username,password and url of the Database

```
@Service
@Configuration
public class SystemSettings implements Settings {  

    public static final String DS_URL = "datasource.app.url";
    public static final String DS_USERNAME = "datasource.app.username";
    public static final String DS_PASSWORD = "datasource.app.password";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        return env.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

The values are picked up from an *application.properties* file as its denoted in the *PersistenceContext* class.

**PersistenceContext**

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();

        String url = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_URL);
        String user = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_USERNAME);
        String pass = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_PASSWORD);

        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(user);
        ds.setPassword(pass);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project.app.services.entities");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        // Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
        // that is optimized for the used database.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        // Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
        // SessionFactory is created or closed.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));  

        // If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
        // statements to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        // If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
        // that is written to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Ans ALSO the **properties** file

> hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop hibernate.show_sql=false
>   hibernate.format_sql=true
>
> datasource.app.type=POSTGRESQL
>   datasource.app.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
>   datasource.app.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app
>   datasource.app.username=user
>   datasource.app.password=pass

Unfortunately now i get this error

> SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>   java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.Driver  at
>   ...... **Caused by:** java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.postgresql.Driver at......

I dont know why it gives me this exception. The maven dependency is there, the driver is also in classpath. . Any help?

This is my project's structure. ou can see the libraries added in build path. As suggested in comments the problem might be that the postgres jar isnt in the tomcat libraries. How do i add it there?
[image]

Comment: Either the jar is not in the classpath or the jar does not contain the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver, Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903481/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql-driver-android)

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325713/postgresql-driver-not-found-for-maven-dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need any class from the Postgres JDBC jar, Modify your dependency to provided. If not just remove it.

```
   <!-- Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1205-jdbc42</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And then add the Postgres JDBC jar to the lib path of tomcat

*{tomcat7_home_path}/lib*

Comment: im sorry but where do i add it. I dont have a local instalation of Tomcat. I use Tomcat from inside Eclipse

Comment: You can see the path in :  windows -> preferences -> servers -> runtime enviroments. Then select your tomcat installation and then the edit button.

Comment: I spent 2 hours trying to debug my connection to local postgres on Spring Tool Suite (STS).  This answer helped tremendously.  I copied the downloaded jar in my local m2 MVN folder and pasted it in {STS install folder\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1\lib }.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you have heirachical classloader issues, where the JDBC driver is visible to your application, but not to Tomcat's connection pool.

See:

- [Why must the JDBC driver be put in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-must-the-jdbc-driver-be-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder)
- https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-jdbc

Comment: Much general answer. Applies even for people who use JDBC drivers from unknown vendors, like e.g. Exasol. Btw, if you want to know how  obscure Exasol is: basically, it's only Exasol developers and me in the whole world who use Exasol.